# How to get integer values from Enum in c#

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have an Enum

```
public enum MyEnum
    {
        value1= 1,
        value2= 2,
        value3= 3,
        value4= 4
    }
```

How do I get the integer values , if I give the string as input , say
input--> value2 , then , output-->2

Thanks

Comment: See [Enumeration types (C# reference) - Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum#conversions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you cam use `Enum.Parse` to parse the string and then cast to int like below :

```
var str  = "value1";
var value = (int)Enum.Parse<MyEnum>(str);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UxfN9p)